# how to apply `text-indent`,`line-height` properties of textarea to resulting pdf document?

Tags: html-to-pdf, pdf-reactor

the pdfreactor server does not apply `text-indent` and `line-height` property of text area. How to fixed?

`<textarea style="height: 79px;width: 767px; text-indent: 63px; background-size: 100% 16px; line-height: 16px; left: 33px;top: 593px;font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial;background-image: none;background-color: white;color: black;">
This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a commentThis is a commentThis is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a commentThis is a commentThis is a comment This is a commentThis is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a commentThis is a commentThis is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a commentThis is a comment This is a comment This is a comment This is a comment 123456789123
</textarea>`

the following images are the show how it renders in browser and pdf(after converted using pdfreactor)

1.0 [image]

above image(1.0) show how it shown in browser.

2.0 [image]

the above (2.0) image shows how it renders after converted to PDF using **pdfreactor**

those images clearly shows the  text-indent and line-height property of text area not applyed when converting the above html snippet. Any solution to render those properties of textarea in **pdfreactor**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with text areas. However, if interactivity of the form element in the PDF is not required, you could re-style the text areas as a normal HTML elements. This could be done like that:

```
textarea {
    -ro-replacedelement: none;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Now the styles "line-height" and "text-indent" will work correctly.

Comment: why `display: block;  border: 1px solid black;` properties?

Comment: The style "display: block" makes the text area behave like a paragraph or "div" element, and the style "border: 1px solid black" is just to mimic the border of normal text areas. Depending on your use case you should of course adapt the styles as needed.